# No address associated with hostname when using pip install on raspbien

Tags: networking, pip

I'm attempting to set up flask to serve as a local webpage to interface with my pi, but for some reason it keeps returning errors when trying to download flask:

```
sudo pip install flask -v
Downloading/unpacking flask
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/flask: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/flask when looking for download links for flask
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for flask
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/ when looking for download links for flask
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement flask
No distributions at all found for flask
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 978, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 157, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for flask

Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anyone know what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Using `sudo apt-get install python flask` returns:

```
sudo apt-get install python-flask
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  javascript-common libjs-jquery python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-openssl python-werkzeug wwwconfig-common
Suggested packages:
  apache2 httpd python-jinja2-doc python-openssl-doc python-openssl-dbg ipython python-genshi python-lxml python-memcache
  libjs-sphinxdoc mysql-client postgresql-client
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  javascript-common libjs-jquery python-flask python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python-openssl python-werkzeug wwwconfig-common
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 149 kB/2,003 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,414 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-openssl armhf 0.13-2+rpi1
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/pyopenssl/python-openssl_0.13-2+rpi1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

Thanks to Joan for the answer -

Running sudo apt-get update seemed to fix any issues with installing flask.

Comment: Does the internet actually work on the Pi? Does `ping 8.8.8.8` do anything? It could also be a problem with one of the commands being called on to download what is required - `wget`, `curl` etc

Comment: Yep, there is an internet connection - pinging websites works fine.

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with not having ran sudo apt-get update beforehand. All is good now.

Comment: then mark @joan 's answer as the answer, or add that as the answer then :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use the one in the repository?  The repository version will be compatible with the other Raspbian modules.

```
apt-cache search flask
checkpolicy - SELinux policy compiler
libselinux1 - SELinux runtime shared libraries
libselinux1-dev - SELinux development headers
libsemanage1 - SELinux policy management library
libsemanage1-dev - Header files and libraries for SELinux policy manipulation
libsepol1 - SELinux library for manipulating binary security policies
policycoreutils - SELinux core policy utilities
python-flask - micro web framework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
python-flaskext.wtf - Simple integration of Flask and WTForms
python-selinux - Python bindings to SELinux shared libraries
python-semanage - Python bindings for SELinux policy management
ruby-selinux - Ruby bindings to SELinux shared libraries
ruby-semanage - Ruby bindings to for SELinux policy management

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-flask
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  javascript-common libjs-jquery python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-openssl python-werkzeug wwwconfig-common
Suggested packages:
  python-jinja2-doc python-openssl-doc python-openssl-dbg ipython
  python-genshi python-lxml python-memcache libjs-sphinxdoc postgresql-client
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  javascript-common libjs-jquery python-flask python-jinja2 python-markupsafe
  python-openssl python-werkzeug wwwconfig-common
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,006 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,422 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main wwwconfig-common all 0.2.2 [22.8 kB]
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libjs-jquery all 1.7.2+dfsg-1 [80.1 kB]
Get:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main javascript-common all 7 [3,810 B]
Get:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-werkzeug all 0.8.3+dfsg-1 [1,486 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-flask all 0.8-1 [79.3 kB]
Get:6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-openssl armhf 0.13-2+rpi1+deb7u1 [152 kB]
Get:7 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-markupsafe armhf 0.15-1 [14.5 kB]
Get:8 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-jinja2 armhf 2.6-1 [167 kB]
Fetched 2,006 kB in 34s (58.5 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package wwwconfig-common.
(Reading database ... 76221 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wwwconfig-common (from .../wwwconfig-common_0.2.2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package javascript-common.
Unpacking javascript-common (from .../javascript-common_7_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjs-jquery.
Unpacking libjs-jquery (from .../libjs-jquery_1.7.2+dfsg-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-werkzeug.
Unpacking python-werkzeug (from .../python-werkzeug_0.8.3+dfsg-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-markupsafe.
Unpacking python-markupsafe (from .../python-markupsafe_0.15-1_armhf.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-jinja2.
Unpacking python-jinja2 (from .../python-jinja2_2.6-1_armhf.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-flask.
Unpacking python-flask (from .../python-flask_0.8-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-openssl.
Unpacking python-openssl (from .../python-openssl_0.13-2+rpi1+deb7u1_armhf.deb) ...
Setting up wwwconfig-common (0.2.2) ...
Setting up javascript-common (7) ...
Setting up libjs-jquery (1.7.2+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up python-werkzeug (0.8.3+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up python-markupsafe (0.15-1) ...
Setting up python-jinja2 (2.6-1) ...
Setting up python-flask (0.8-1) ...
Setting up python-openssl (0.13-2+rpi1+deb7u1) ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
hard /ram $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>>
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-flask doesn't seem to actually install flask. I get an import error when trying to import it in a simple helloworld script.

Comment: I just installed using apt-get install and import flask works within Python.  Perhaps the failed pip has mucked up your system.

Comment: gah, should I just reinstall raspbian?

Comment: I'd try a sudo apt-get purge python-flask and then a sudo apt-get install python flask.  Sometimes that sort of invocation tidies up a mess.  Remember I'm only guessing that pip mucked up your system.

Comment: I actually went ahead and reinstalled raspbian and had the same issue of flask not installing even with sudo-apt get install python-flask. purging flask returns that "Package 'python-flask' is not installed, so not removed.

Comment: Yesterday I installed on a Debian Pi.  I have just done exactly the same on a Raspbian Pi.  It installs OK and imports OK into Python.  Have you done a sudo apt-get update?  I don't see why that would be needed, but who knows.

Comment: Yep, sudo apt-get update seems to have fixed it. Thanks a bunch.